# Substring Integers from String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, xcode, ipad

How can I substring integer values from a string (which I am getting from an Sensex Website) ?

Like : I am getting some values like "SENSEX : 18446.5 * 623.10 (3.50)" the value I need is **18446.5**.
In java I can do it by using subString method. How to do it in Objective C ?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to use substring, there is 3 methods :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use substring, there is 3 methods that you can apply on a NSString:

```
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from;
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)to;
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substringWithRange:` method on an NSString.

Take a look at the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). There is a quite a collection of methods for manipulating strings. e.g. You could use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to break up your string into an array of strings, and then use `floatValue` to convert one of those strings to a number.